# How does Matlab implement knnclassify?

Tags: matlab

Anyone have any idea how knnclassify is implemented in Matlab? I was wondering if they use a kd-tree for efficient distance computations. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `edit knnclassify` to see the source? If they're not using a C++ implementation, you can see exactly what they've been doing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hadnt even considered that. I just checked and they use knnsearch which I also opened and that has its own compiled code. In any case I implemented my own version of knnclassify that works about ten thousand time faster using matlabs own vectorization so i think its pretty ridiculous they couldnt have gone to the effort of optimizing their own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `matlab` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html) related to this is very clear. However your question about `... use a kd-tree for efficient distance computations` is not quite so clear.

I mainly mean who cares, but if you do; then do some timings between alternatives.

Anyway the question with 'rules'-parameter is way much more complicated, than just finding out some simple `kd-tree` usage. So please really try to time your operations first and if they are not sufficient somehow, I'll surely be able to fine tune them for you then!

Comment: Youre right. I didnt word it very clearly. i didnt mean how they compute the distances themselves but instead how they compare the distances. And that really does matter because brute force is O(n^2) which for a matrix with over 2000 elements starts becoming timely.